# How to use a variable inside IN operator

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, in-operator

I'm trying to write an application in C# that will pass a variable that contains multiple value separated by a comma, to a stored procedure

```
string state = "AZ, CA, VA"
```

I want my stored procedure to return all data for each state in the variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetStateInfo
@state varchar(2)

SELECT * FROM StateTable WHERE state IN (@state)
```

But when I do the code above I get an error saying 'Incorrect syntax'
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Use single quotes: "'AZ', 'CA', 'VA'"

Comment: I assume you're talking SQL-server (T-SQL)? What's your current code for calling the procedure?

Comment: there are examples on the internet as well in regards to how to use the reserved word `IN` in sql have you tried a google search..?

Comment: The issue I'm having right now is when I'm creating the stored procedure. Whenever I try to execute the stored procedure it gives me the error

Comment: The possible duplicate from @DylanNicholson is the one you want. `IN` looks for a value in list. A string isn't a list. You can send a table valued parameter - a list of values - and then join to it.

Comment: varchar(2) only gives you 2 characters...Try varchar(MAX) to be optimistic :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use multiple inputs as parameter for IN statement. You will have to split those comma separated values in SQL to create a table variable and join with that table variable.

You can create a function for splitting input string :-

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[udf_PutStringtoTableUnique]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_PutStringtoTableUnique]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE function [dbo].[udf_PutStringtoTableUnique]  
(         
      @inputStr as varchar(max),  
      @delim nchar(1) = N','    
)    
returns @tbl table(ID int primary key)    
as    
BEGIN    

if @inputStr = '' or @inputStr is null
return 

declare @tags nchar(2)
set @tags = @delim + @delim;

with tbl_for_csv as    
(    
select left(@inputStr + @tags,charindex(@delim,@inputStr + @tags) -1)as Col,     
right(@inputStr + @tags,len(@inputStr + @tags) - charindex(@delim,@inputStr + @tags)) as Str    
union all    
select left(Str,charindex(@delim,Str) - 1)as Col,     
right(Str,len(Str) - charindex(@delim,Str)) from tbl_for_csv    
where len(right(Str,len(Str) - charindex(@delim,Str))) > 0    
)    
insert into @tbl    
select distinct Col from tbl_for_csv    
option (maxrecursion 0)    

return 
END

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

And Then write something like this in procedure :-

```
DECLARE @TempStates Table (StateName Varchar(2))

INSERT INTO @TempStates
Select id from [dbo].[udf_PutStringtoTableUnique](@state, ',')

    SELECT * FROM StateTable 
    INNER JOIN @TempStates temp ON state = temp.StateName
```

Comment: Nice, but cumbersome solution.  I'm sure this would work but UDF are awfully slow

Comment: THat's a simple udf and won't take much time... I have tried the same on bulky data as well.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, if they are not used inline then they are acceptable...When used inline (in a select) they can really bog down speed.

Comment: Yeah...Agreed Grantly..Better to have a table variable to store function's result n use it. Editing that query...

Comment: thats a good idea :)  I'll try to remember that

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` operator accepts an inline list of values, or a `select` statement. There is no native `list` type of variable in SQL. And certainly `varchar(2)` will not work, as you have it.

As you are using C#, it makes sense to loop through a list of states, calling the stored procedure for each element. The procedure would use `=` instead of `IN` to filter the states.

If you insist that the procedure accept a string of comma-separated values, then you would have to use SQL commands to split the string and insert each value into a temp table or table variable, to then have a `select` statement for the `IN`to consume.

In T-SQL, you can do this with `STRING_SPLIT()` for SQL Server 2016 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM StateTable
WHERE state IN(
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@states, ',') )
```

Comment: Awesome, what version of SQL supports STRING_SPLIT?  BTW this is a very effective answer to a problem all of us have had at some point...

Comment: LOL 2016....I'm still using 2008...I would be using '95 if it was supported

Comment: Unfortunately String_Split has been introduced in 2016 n available only under compatibility level 130. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still using 2005